# How to omit certain folders on ido-switch-buffers and ido-dired?

Tags: emacs, dired, ido

I would like to ignore certain folders turning up via `ido-dired` when changing buffers in Emacs. These folders are system folders on a Mac and should not be removed otherwise, so at least I would like to hide them (especially annoying is, for example, `~/Documents` which is suggested when one wants to change to `~/Downloads` and thus starts to type `Do...`).

To this end, I found `ido-ignore-directories` and I used the following line in `.emacs` to omit these folders:

```
(setq ido-ignore-directories (quote ("~/Applications" "~/Documents" "~/Library" "~/Movies" "~/Music" "~/Pictures" "~/Public")))
```

The problem is, that they are still suggested when I use `ido-dired`.

How can the folders be hidden on `ido-dired`?

**Update**

When setting `ido-ignore-directories` as suggested by npostavs, the folder still appear: [image]

Comment: Do you mean `ido-switch-buffer`? For this you need to set `ido-ignore-buffers`. Notice that it needs to be a regex or a function, so a plain string will not do. I'm afraid `ido-dired` does not have such a variable.

Comment: Hi, yes, I meant `ido-switch-buffer` (I'll correct it, thanks). `ido-ignore-buffers` is only for ignoring files, but not *folders* (as far as I have understood). 
I mainly use `ido-dired`... it's unfortunate that it's not possible for that.

Comment: I'm lost. You talk about `ido-switch-buffer` and then about directories. That makes no sense. `ido-switch-buffer` switches between buffers, it does not care what the buffer represents.

Comment: ahh, right, `ido-switch-buffer` is probably wrong... if the folder doesn't appear as a buffer, it should not appear. I updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To this end, I found `ido-ignore-directories` and I used the following line in .emacs to omit these folders:
>
> ```
> (setq ido-ignore-directories (quote ("~/Applications" "~/Documents" "~/Library" "~/Movies" "~/Music" "~/Pictures" "~/Public")))
> ```

`ido-ignore-directories` is the correct variable, but it matches just the directory name itself, not the full path.

```
(setq ido-ignore-directories
      '("Applications/" "Documents/" "Library/" "Movies/" "Music/" "Pictures/" "Public/"))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. I tried that, deleted all the buffers (just in case), but if I want to change to `Downloads`, then still `Documents` is suggested first, for example (see my screenshot). Hmmm...

Comment: sorry, I realize now that what I tested to work for myself, was slightly different than what I posted, because I misinterpreted the reason for your settings not working. Updated with an actual working setting now.